# Test module method with rspec-mocks

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, mocking, rspec-mocks

How to test config method in this module with Rspec 3 mocks?

```
module TestModule
  class << self
    attr_accessor :config
  end
  def self.config
    @config ||= Config.new
  end
  class Config
    attr_accessor :money_url
    def initialize
      @money_url = "https://example1.come"
    end
  end
end
```

I tried something like this:

```
describe "TestModule config" do
  it "should have config instance" do
    config = class_double("TestModule::Config")
    obj = instance_double("TestModule")
    allow(obj).to receive(:config).and_return(config)
    obj.config
    expect(obj.config).to eq(config)
  end
end
```

It looks, that it doesn't works, why ?

> Failures:
>
> 1) TestModule config should have config instance
>        Failure/Error: allow(obj).to receive(:config).and_return(config)
>          TestModule does not implement: config
>        # ./spec/config_spec.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend testing the class directly with

```
describe "module config" do
  it "has config" do
    expect(TestModule.config).to be kind_of(TestModule::Config)
  end
end
```

If you don't need the `.config` to be changed by an outside object, then there's no need to have the `attr_accessor :config` as the `def self.config` already defines a accessible `.config` method to `TestModule`. If you want to allow `.config` to be changed from the outside, then just having a `attr_writer :config` should suffice as the reader/getter is already defined as that method.

Moreover, if you already have your class open with `class << self`, then declaring the `.config` method inside that would make more sense as it would contain all class level definitions. Just drop the `self.` from the beginning of the declaration so it reads `def config` as you are already "inside" the class.

Comment: Sorry, I hope you don't think I stole your answer. You submitted this while I was in the process of updating my original response. I think we're both agreed on the solution, though. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you mixed up class_double and instance_double. Try switching them and see how it goes. (sent from mobile phone so forgive my brevity)

**UPDATE:** Now that I'm at a computer, I can dig into this a bit more. First, why are you stubbing the method you're testing? Aren't you trying to test that it returns an instance of the `Config` class? By stubbing the `.config` method, you're not really testing your method to prove that it does what you want it to do. I think you could really simplify this to something like:

```
RSpec.describe TestModule do
  describe ".config" do
    it "returns an Config instance" do
      expect(TestModule.config).to be_a TestModule::Config
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Also, TestModule is not an object instance so your test is a bit confusing the way it's written.